# JButtons and JLabels are not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

What is wrong with my code? My buttons and the labels are not appearing.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HelloPanelLabel extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloPanelLabel(); // creates an instance of frame class
    }

    public HelloPanelLabel() {

        this.setSize(200, 100);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Hello World!");
        this.setVisible(true);

        Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d= tk.getScreenSize();
        int x=(d.height/2);
        int y=(d.width/2);
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        //JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("hello, world");
        //panel1.add(label1);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
        //panel1.add(button1);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the first `this.setVisible(true)` call

Comment: Why don't you uncomment your last 3 lines,`add()` the panel and call `pack();` to see what happens. Also take @Robin advice.

Comment: @Robin please was there reason to delete this answer, is correct ....

Comment: @mKorbel I forgot to mention to uncomment the `add` statements which was already addressed in other answers

Comment: Thanks all for your help on this, great support

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and add your components to the frame.

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("hello, world");
add(label1);
//panel1.add(label1);
JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
add(button1);
//panel1.add(button1);
 this.setVisible(true);
```

Like the comments stated, you have to call `pack()`. However, if you want to define more complex layouts, you will have to create a more complex.

Comment: It's not necessary to set a layout. Since `FlowLayout`is by default. Just add the `JComponents`,and call `pack()`.

Comment: @user2336315 I want to correct my statement, I was wrong you have to add a layout!!!Instead on `JPanel` it seems there is no need.

Comment: @user2336315 Not really. You will only see the last component, in this case the `JButton`. Why don't you test it

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not showing of `JButton` and `JLabel` is that you have not added the `JPanel` containing these two components to the `JFrame`.You just need a little modification in your code. Here is that:

```
panel1.add(label1);
JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
panel1.add(button1);
getContentPane().add(panel1);//Add to ContentPane of JFrame
this.setVisible(true);
```

And remove the the previous `this.setVisible(true)` line in your programe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `JPanel` for your components

```
public class HelloPanelLabel extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloPanelLabel().setVisible(true);
    }

    public HelloPanelLabel() {
        //The same as setTitle.
        super("Hello World!");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("hello, world");
        panel1.add(label1);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
        panel1.add(button1);
        add(panel1);
        //Size the frame to fit the components
        pack();

        //Center the frame.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

alternatively you can add them directly to the `contentPane` of the `JFrame`.

```
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("hello, world");
    add(label1);
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
    add(button1);

    Toolkit theKit = getToolkit();
    Dimension wndSize = theKit.getScreenSize();

    setSize(wndSize.width / 8, wndSize.height / 12);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help. This worked fine. What does the add(panel1)do?

Comment: @user1156718 When you add a component in a container you use the `add()` method, similarly when you add a container. With the difference you add it to a top level container. See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html. **Please don't forget to select an answer if you find a solution**